# I TRIED but InvokeMember Click is NOT working on the INPUT BUTTON, it's very different from the others

Tags: c#, javascript, html, button, input

I wanted button9 to automatically click an input button in the html page using webbrowser1.

This is the code of the input button below. I got this from the page source.

```
 <input type="image" name="phmiddle_0$ShoppingCartOrderSummary1$btnCheckout"
 id="phmiddle_0_ShoppingCartOrderSummary1_btnCheckout" title="Checkout"
 src="/content/images/global/buttons/checkout.gif" onclick="return
 GMCR.CheckoutValidation();" style="border-width:0px;">
```

So this is the code I used below to click it.

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("phmiddle_0$ShoppingCartOrderSummary1$btnCheckout").InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

And I also tried this

```
 private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("phmiddle_0_ShoppingCartOrderSummary1_btnCheckout").InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

None of those two worked.

I also tried some other very long codes out there that contain var and htmlelement tags but none of them worked.

Please help me, what am I doing wrong here.

I clicked button9, but it does not automatically click the input button.

Comment: I FOUND THE ANSWER

ALL I HAVE TO DO IS ADD THIS

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("phmiddle_0_ShoppingCartOrderSummary1_btnCheckout").RaiseEvent("onclick");

Answer (score 1):

I FOUND THE ANSWER ALL I HAVE TO DO IS ADD THIS webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("phmiddle_0_ShoppingCartOrderSummary1_btnChe‌​ckout").RaiseEvent("onclick");